# Deleting Website, getting a 403 from CloudFront instead of redirection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I have an older website that was hosted in S3 fronted by CloudFront. I have a new website that is a replacement for that and I have hosted that in AWS Amplify and moved the domain record from GoDaddy to Route 53. The `CNAME` for this in Route 53 points the older domain to the new domain.

I have deleted the CloudFront entry from the older account as well as access to the S3 bucket. However, trying to access the URL still shows the below error.

[image: HTTPS]
[image: HTTP]

Any idea how we can solve for this?

Comment: CloudFront would have to know the old domain

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of your post, you probably also need to add the alternate domain name to your CloudFront distribution and make sure your certificate allows for that domain name.